# Unable to add window android.view.ViewRootImpl$W@2231e0c -- permission denied for window type 2003

Tags: android

I am using overlay permission to display certain information in my app.
it work in < api level 25 but in api 26 ... 
when i run my app it display over other apps but when i click it to open the dialog like assistive touch ... it shows the error ...
"Unable to add window android.view.ViewRootImpl$W@2231e0c -- permission denied for window type 2003"

Trying on API 26 I am getting an error, basically "permission denied for window type 2003" when clicked

[image]

```
 params = new WindowManager.LayoutParams(
                WindowManager.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                WindowManager.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_APPLICATION_OVERLAY,
                WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_FOCUSABLE
                        | WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_TOUCH_MODAL
                        | WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_WATCH_OUTSIDE_TOUCH
                        | WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_LAYOUT_NO_LIMITS,
                PixelFormat.TRANSLUCENT);
        params.gravity = Gravity.CENTER | Gravity.START;
        params.x = 100;
        params.y = 50;
        windowManager = (WindowManager) getSystemService(WINDOW_SERVICE);
        windowManager.addView(floatingView, params);
```

Error is ......

```
E/MessageQueue-JNI: android.view.WindowManager$BadTokenException: Unable to add window android.view.ViewRootImpl$W@2231e0c -- permission denied for window type 2003
    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.setView(ViewRootImpl.java:982)
    at android.view.WindowManagerGlobal.addView(WindowManagerGlobal.java:381)
    at android.view.WindowManagerImpl.addView(WindowManagerImpl.java:100)
    at android.app.Dialog.show(Dialog.java:420)
    at com.absomech.floatingapp.FloatingViewService.myDialog(FloatingViewService.java:610)
    at com.absomech.floatingapp.FloatingViewService.access$100(FloatingViewService.java:46)
    at com.absomech.floatingapp.FloatingViewService$3.onTouch(FloatingViewService.java:188)
    at android.view.View.dispatchTouchEvent(View.java:12536)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:3153)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2829)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:3159)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2844)
    at android.view.View.dispatchPointerEvent(View.java:12788)
    at android.view.ViewRootImpl$ViewPostImeInputStage.processPointerEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:5670)
    at android.view.ViewRootImpl$ViewPostImeInputStage.onProcess(ViewRootImpl.java:5465)
    at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.deliver(ViewRootImpl.java:4958)
    at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.onDeliverToNext(ViewRootImpl.java:5011)
    at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.forward(ViewRootImpl.java:4977)
    at android.view.ViewRootImpl$AsyncInputStage.forward(ViewRootImpl.java:5114)
    at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.apply(ViewRootImpl.java:4985)
    at android.view.ViewRootImpl$AsyncInputStage.apply(ViewRootImpl.java:5171)
    at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.deliver(ViewRootImpl.java:4958)
    at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.onDeliverToNext(ViewRootImpl.java:5011)
    at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.forward(ViewRootImpl.java:4977)
    at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.apply(ViewRootImpl.java:4985)
    at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.deliver(ViewRootImpl.java:4958)
    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.deliverInputEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:7736)
    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doProcessInputEvents(ViewRootImpl.java:7676)
    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.enqueueInputEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:7637)
    at android.view.ViewRootImpl$WindowInputEventReceiver.onInputEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:7847)
    at android.view.InputEventReceiver.dispatchInputEvent(InputEventReceiver.java:197)
    at android.os.MessageQueue.nativePollOnce(Native Method)
    at android.os.MessageQueue.next(MessageQueue.java:325)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:142)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6944)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.Zygote$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(Zygote.java:327)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1374)
```

Comment: erroe on  dialog.show();